# Differences in display of parameters between GNU Radio 3.7 and 3.8

Tags: gnuradio, gnuradio-companion

I am porting multi-rtl to GNU Radio 3.8. I've actually done all the porting and I already have a program that works. Now only a few cosmetic changes are missing, such as new examples. When I wanted to make a new example, I realized that the block is displayed for me differently than in the picture. Here is this picture from documentation (original program):
[image]

Here is how this block is displayed for me (in my ported program):
[image]

It's even expected behavior. Here are parameters of this block (they're generated for each n in this way):

```
-   id: sync_gain${n}
    label: "Ch${n}: Sync RF Gain (dB)"
    category: Synchronization
    dtype: real
    default: 10
    hide: ${"$"}{ 'part' if nchan > ${n} else 'all' }
-   id: freq${n}
    label: "Ch${n}: Frequency (Hz)"
    category: RF Options
    dtype: real
    default: 100e6
    hide: ${"$"}{ 'none' if nchan > ${n} else 'all' }
-   id: gain${n}
    label: "Ch${n}: RF Gain (dB)"
    category: RF Options
    dtype: real
    default: 10
    hide: ${"$"}{ 'part' if nchan > ${n} else 'all' }
-   id: gain_mode${n}
    label: "Ch${n}: Gain Mode"
    category: RF Options
    dtype: bool
    default: False
    hide: ${"$"}{ 'part' if nchan > ${n} else 'all' }
    options: [ False, True ]
    option_labels: [ Manual, Automatic ]
-   id: id_string${n}
    label: "Ch${n}: ID string"
    dtype: string
    default: "${n}"
    hide: ${"$"}{ 'part' if nchan > ${n} else 'all' }
```

The only parameter with the hide option set to none is "Ch $ {n}: Frequency (Hz)" so it's also only parameter that is displayed "outside". It's normal. However, I do not understand why the equivalent of this code in gnuradio 3.7 is displayed differently. Here's GNU Radio 3.7 code that I think is equivalent:

```
<param>
  <name>Ch$(n): Sync RF Gain (dB)</name>
  <key>sync_gain$(n)</key>
  <value>10</value>
  <type>real</type>
  <hide>\#if \$nchan() > $n then 'part' else 'all'#</hide>
  <tab>Synchronization</tab>
</param>
<param>
  <name>Ch$(n): Frequency (Hz)</name>
  <key>freq$(n)</key>
  <value>100e6</value>
  <type>real</type>
  <hide>\#if \$nchan() > $n then 'none' else 'all'#</hide>
  <tab>RF Options</tab>
</param>
<param>
  <name>Ch$(n): RF Gain (dB)</name>
  <key>gain$(n)</key>
  <value>10</value>
  <type>real</type>
  <hide>\#if \$nchan() > $n then 'part' else 'all'#</hide>
  <tab>RF Options</tab>
</param>
<param>
  <name>Ch$(n): Gain Mode</name>
  <key>gain_mode$(n)</key>
  <value>False</value>
  <type>bool</type>
  <hide>\#if \$nchan() > $n then 'part' else 'all'#</hide>
  <option>
    <name>Manual</name>
    <key>False</key>
  </option>
  <option>
    <name>Automatic</name>
    <key>True</key>
  </option>
  <tab>RF Options</tab>
</param>
<param>
  <name>Ch$(n): ID string</name>
  <key>id_string$(n)</key>
  <value>"$(n)"</value>
  <type>string</type>
  <hide>\#if \$nchan() > $n then 'part' else 'all'#</hide>
</param>
```

Why are they displayed differently?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why are they displayed differently?

Probably some bug in your gnuradio 3.7 version. I just tested it with gnuradio 3.7.13.5 and the displayed block is similar to your gnuradio 3.8 example.

[image]

If you want to see all parameters change `'part'` to `'none'`. See also https://wiki.gnuradio.org/index.php/YAML_GRC#Parameters